# Why must I use numbers when displaying SSHFP DNS records?

Tags: dns

I'm writing a DNS client, where records are queried and shown to the user, and I'm adding support for the SSHFP record type, which stores SSH fingerprints. Records of this type have three fields:

1. The public key algorithm number (where 1 is RSA, 2 is DSS, 3 is ECDSA, among others)
2. The hashing algorithm number (where 1 is SHA1, 2 is SHA-256)
3. The fingerprint itself

After parsing the first two numbers from the packet, I was ready to write code to display "DSS" or "SHA1" for the algorithm fields, instead of just displaying "2" and "1". However, in [§3.2 of RFC 4255](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4255#section-3.2), which specifies the record type, this is *explicitly forbidden* (bolded for emphasis):

> The RDATA of the presentation format of the SSHFP resource record
> consists of two numbers (algorithm and fingerprint type) followed by
> the fingerprint itself, presented in hex, e.g.:
>
> ```
>    host.example.  SSHFP 2 1 123456789abcdef67890123456789abcdef67890
> ```
>
> **The use of mnemonics instead of numbers is not allowed.**

Why is this the case? Surely anyone who reads these numbers will go and look them up anyway, and as this is a presentation format rather than a data format, the underlying data will be the same no matter how it's shown to a user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *presentation format* is part of established DNS terminology, as explained in [RFC 8499, 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8499#section-5):

> **Master file:**  "Master files are text files that contain RRs in text
> form.  Since the contents of a zone can be expressed in the form
> of a list of RRs a master file is most often used to define a
> zone, though it can be used to list a cache's contents."  (Quoted
> from [[RFC1035], Section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-5)) Master files are sometimes called "zone
> files".
>
> **Presentation format:**  The text format used in master files.  This
> format is shown but not formally defined in [[RFC1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034)] or
> [[RFC1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035)].  The term "presentation format" first appears in
> [[RFC4034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4034)].

It is in the *master files* or *zone*s where you should use this *presentation format*. GUI clients and configuration interfaces are free to present the data however they like, and they do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the statement you cite forbids the use of algorithm names instead of numbers when displaying the information to the user. It is instead about the format of the DNS record only, i.e. what the standard is actually about. It just means that using algorithm names in the DNS record instead of numbers would violate the standard.